# ownCloud 6 Upgrade -- Lucene

Tags: upgrade, lucene, owncloud

I've upgraded ownCloud to 6 (*just release*) on a CentOS 6.4 (*x86_64*) server via `yum update` (*no other changes*) and the upgrade has failed with this in the `owncloud.log` file: http://codepad.org/wRRGNk22

Has anyone got a fix for this?

I've tried:

- Deleting the table
- Truncating the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug.

You can follow it at https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/4085.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :) I think I upgraded on the day it was release!

Comment: That bug report seems somewhat related but slightly different and relating to ownCloud 5.x hmmm

Comment: Have also a look at https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/6313#issuecomment-30343223

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated! Hopefully there'll be a new bug fix release shortly :)